# Django-South not detecting addition of default value on field

Tags: django, django-models, django-south

So, I added a default value to a Django model field, then ran:

```
$ python manage.py schemamigration myapp --auto
```

Nothing seems to have changed.

Wha duh?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for a migration for `default` value. Because, the default value is read by the django application, and adds the specified `default` value to the Raw SQL that it generates add the time of add/update

Comment: Thanks for the replies, however, without some sort of migration, previously recorded null values for this field will not have the newly specified default value... So, I have to reconcile by another avenue?

Comment: For you to achieve that, you can do a `.update()` in django shell for the queryset object. You cannot it by south.

Comment: Well, in the end, the solution for me was to, in the model, also set: 
`null=False`, which induced a south migration script, then add to the generated migration script: `orm['myapp.mymodel'].objects.filter(some_field__isnull=True).update(some_field=0)`, thus providing default values for legacy entries.

Comment: Oh.. Now you made that field required. Is that acceptable? Now, it would apply the default value because there was a migration, However the right way to have done it would be to either run a management command, or to update it in django shell

Comment: Maybe, but using update means I'd have to manually do that across all servers running the app, and if you have multiple envs, well... with the above approach, on commit, I'm all done... But, but I'll try your method next!  Thanks!

Comment: ...and in this case, the field cannot be null, so null=False is valid.

Comment: Sure.. As long as it works :) There is something called `fabric` which you might want to look at to do same thing on multiple app servers

Comment: So, the migration script then looks like:  
`class Migration(SchemaMigration):

    def forwards(self, orm):
        if not db.dry_run:
            # convert nulls to default values to avoid "Data truncated" error
            orm['myapp.mymodel'].objects.filter(some_field__isnull=True).update(some_field=0)

            # etc...`

Comment: In fact, to force old null fields to update to default values, you need to force `NOT NULL` in the database anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to make that by south. Its already there , you can change that whenever you want.